# Updating a UILabel from another view using NSNotificationCenter

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel, nsnotificationcenter

I'm updating a UILabel in another view using a method invoked using the NSNotification center.

What I'm finding is that it's not working, the label remains unchanged until the view is reloaded at a later point (not using the method called by nsnotification center).

The label is set to nonatomic, retain and I'm using self to bind everything to that property.

obviously all of the code (the method) that tries to update the label is located in the corresponding viewController. The method gets called (I can see that with NSLog), and all it does is self.label2.text = @"label 2 updated";

I'm able to update the text value of the label using a timer just fine, so I don't think there is a problem with the label, but rather with my understanding of threading and/or what is loaded or not at a given time.

What do you think is the problem?

PS: i WILL chose an answer even if it doesn't help me that much, so please post your wildest guesses!

Comment: "i WILL chose an answer even if it doesn't help me that much": please don't do that.

Comment: hah, well naturally I won't choose one that doesn't help at ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that your label is not `nil` when you set the text.

If it's not `nil`, try calling `setNeedsLayout` on your label after setting the text (this shouldn't be necessary). Also, verify that you are on the main thread with:

```
[NSThread isMainThread]
```

If that doesn't help, use a subclass of `UILabel`, override `setText` and put a breakpoint on it to see what's going on.

Comment: thx for the answer! I just checked and I'm on mainthread, and the label is not nill..

do I just call setNeedsLayout on the instance/ property like [self.label setNeedsLayout]; when I try and update?